# component functions and coordinates of linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $A(a, b, c)$ and $A'(a',b',c')$ be two distinct points in $\mathbb R^3$. Let $f$ from $[0 , 1]$ to $\mathbb R^3$ be defined by $f(t) = (1 - t) A + t A'$. Instead of calling the component functions of $f$ $(f_1, f_2, f_3)$ let us simply write $f = (x, y, z)$. Express $x; y; z$ in terms of the coordinates of $A$ and $A'$, and $t$.

I thought that $a$ is the partial derivative of $f_1$ with respect to $x$, $b$ is the partial derivative of $f_2$ with respect to $y$, and $c$ is the partial derivative of $f_3$ with respect to $z$. I am right? Any hint how to find the relation?

Answer (score 0):

Just write the vectors out:

$$f=(1-t)\begin{pmatrix}a\\
b\\
c\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}a'\\b'\\c'\end{pmatrix}$$

So

$$x=(1-t)a+ta'\\
y=(1-t)b+tb'\\
z=(1-t)c+tc'$$

This is the line connecting $A$ and $A'$.